# Sets A such that A+A contains the largest set [0,1,..,t]

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I look for a reference for the following problem.
Given an integer $k$, find a set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ with $|A|=k$
that maximizes $t$ such that $\left[0,1,..,t\right]\subset A+A$.

Comment: For low numbers:$$k=1, t=0: \{0\}$$ $$k=2, t=2: \{0,1\}$$ $$k=3, t=4: \{0,1,2\} \text{ or } \{0,1,3\}$$ $$k=4, t=8: \{0,1,3,4\}$$

Comment: $$k=5, t=12: \{0,1,3,5,6\}$$Also, https://Oeis.org/A126684 can be used to find lower bounds for $t$. However, none of its OEIS cross-references begin with $0,2,4,8,12$, and none of the OEIS sequences beginning $0,2,4,8,12$ look promising -- so existing literature may have little to say on the sequence in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A table of values for these $t$ are given in the introduction Graham and Sloane's [On Additive Bases and Harmonius Graphs](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0601045) (your sequence corresponds to $n_\beta(k)$ in their notation).  Graham and Sloane also give some references to previous work with this sequence, both under the name of "interval basis" (or Abschnittsbasis), going back to a paper in German from [Rohrbach](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=149865&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=27&mx-pid=1545658) in the 1930's, and under the name of "The Postage Stamp Problem".

This is sequence A001212 [in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001212), which has additional references.

Comment: Glad you found this or knew it! Now I see why I missed it...I got confused by not seeing 0's and thinking that the postage stamp problem was about two-dimensional configurations of stamps instead.

Answer (score 5):

This is related to ``thin additive bases" of order $2$.   Clearly $t$ cannot be larger than $k(k+1)/2$.   It is also possible to give examples where $t$ grows quadratically.  Take $A=A_0 \cup A_1$ where $A_0$ contains all integers below 
$t$ with binary expansion $\sum_{j} \epsilon_j 2^j$ with $\epsilon_j= 0$ unless $j$ is even, and $A_1$ consists of numbers with binary digits $\epsilon_j=0$ unless $j$ is odd.  Then $A$ has $O(\sqrt{t})$ elements in it; or alternatively $t\ge Ck^2$ for some constant $C>0$.   See for example this paper of [Blomer](https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/blomer/Paper1.pdf) which has other references.

Comment: or simply take $A=\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}\cup \{m,2m,3m,\ldots,m^2\}$ for $m=\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$